# Can not find / install ffmpeg and nasm with homebrew in MacOS

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew

When I try to install ffmpeg using brew, I am prompted to install the “nasm” formula first. However, when I tried to install “nasm” formula,  made the following error

```sh
➜  ~ brew install ffmpeg                
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 5 casks.

Warning: No available formula with the name "nasm" (dependency of homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg).
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
➜  ~ brew install nasm
Warning: No available formula with the name "nasm".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Comment: Looking at the [formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg), there's a note it depends on `nasm` and `pkg-config`. Do those casks need to be installed first?

Comment: Oops, my mistake! I see you tried to `brew install nasm` after the first error. What version is `brew`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (long ago) I *might* have tried brew to install FFmpeg and got stuck. In the end, I installed it manually:

```bash
# 1. Install the zipped executable, or visit https://ffmpeg.org
curl -JL -o ~/Downloads/ffmpeg.zip https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/get/zipcurl -JL -o ~/Downloads/ffmpeg.zip https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/get/zip

# 2. Inflate/extract executable file
unzip ~/Downloads/ffmpeg.zip -d ~/Downloads/ffmpeg

# 3. Move file into executables directory
cp ~/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

# 4. Allow file to execute
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg

# 5. Quick check
file /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
# /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

# 6. Ready set go!
ffmpeg
```

Source: I struggled with this and wrote [a post on my personal site](https://sarahgrefalda.me/journal/installing-ffmpeg/), recently updated.